# How to set the Preferred applications on Ubuntu MATE 20.04, for a given user?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, default-programs, mime-type

On Ubuntu MATE 18.04, I could add and set preferred applications, for a given user, this way:

```sh
# Create an application entry

cat > ~/.local/share/applications/browser.desktop << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=My Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
...
EOF

# Replace the entry in the list of preferred applications

sed -i "1clocation:$HOME/.local/share/applications/browser.desktop" ~/.config/mate-menu/applications.list

# Associate the MIME types

xdg-mime default "browser.desktop" "x-scheme-handler/http"
xdg-mime default "browser.desktop" "x-scheme-handler/https"
```

The problem is that on 20.04, the two directories don't exist.

I see that there are the global files exist, but I'd still prefer to change for the user only (because the entry created invokes files available for that user only).

If I create the missing directories and the content, there is no effect.

Is this possible?

Comment: Consider to ask on https://ubuntu-mate.community/ for better results too :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try also there.

Comment: @N0rbert sadly, it seems also there nobody has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran into the same issue and found a solution. At least as of Ubuntu 22.04, you can set these per user in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` You'll then set the appropriate mime-types to the desktop file of your application, which should live in `/usr/share/applications`.

Incidentally, I figured out which ones need to be changed by looking at the source code to the `mate-default-application-settings` tool here: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/blob/master/capplets/default-applications/mate-da-capplet.c (`set_changed` function on lines 66-178.)